# How to Have two copies of an Object

Tags: objects

I am new to Blender. I want to make Minecraft animations. I have been taking a 5-episode tutorial on how to do that by BlackPlasmaStudios.

I am using their custom-made easy-to-use MineCraft character model, but I can't figure out how to have two of them in the scene. When I have two, I can't delete the second one, I can't move it, and I can't switch modes with it. And when I have it selected, it has no X-Y-Z axis to move it, and the outline is blue.

I cannot figure it out. Also, when I go to delete it, it just says, *Cannot Delete. Indirectly used objects need at least one user.*

It is disabled rendering for itself, selecting for itself, and viewing for itself. I just can't figure it out.
Tell me if you need a screenshot of it.

Comment: We need a screenshot and a description of how your model is made or works.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. What the problem was is that I didn't move the 1st object above the surface of the scene before appending the other. But thanks for the help anyway.